# node, socket.io - connect to list of news feed urls?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I wish to connect to the list of news feed urls via `node` and get the real-time data via `socket.io`. For that I tried with single url in `server.js` as below:

```
var http = require("http");
var options = {
    host: 'http://economictimes.feedsportal.com/c/33041/f/534037/'
};

http.get(options, function (http_res) {
    // initialize the container for our data
    var data = "";

    // this event fires many times, each time collecting another piece of the response
    http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        // append this chunk to our growing `data` var
        data += chunk;
    });

    // this event fires *one* time, after all the `data` events/chunks have been gathered
    http_res.on("end", function () {
        // you can use res.send instead of console.log to output via express
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

When I execute `node server.js`, it throws me an error

```
"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)"
```

**Is there any way to pass each news feed url from an array to connect it via `node` and get latest news via `socket.io` ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [node doc for the `http` module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), this is what a typical options object looks like:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};
```

Per the doc, the `host` option you are using should be `A domain name or IP address of the server to issue the request to. Defaults to 'localhost'.`  So, it looks like you just aren't calling `.get()` correctly.

If you just want to pass the whole URL, then don't use the options object, just pass the URL like this and the method will parse the URL for you into the relevant parts:

```
http.get('http://economictimes.feedsportal.com/c/33041/f/534037/', function (http_res) {...});
```

Comment: From your solution I am able to get the data. Could you please throw some light on how do I send data to client via `socket.io` ???

Comment: @ChakoDesai - You haven't really asked a specific question about `socket.io`.  There are plenty of examples here: http://socket.io/docs/.  I'm not sure what you want beyond that.  If you need more help with that, please start a new question for that as it's a separate issue from fetching the content.

Comment: I've already raised a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199250/socket-io-redis-possible-architecture-for-news-feed)