# How do I notify the client socket when there is an update on server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

First let me give you background with the question I've already asked here. [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295377/node-socket-io-update-client-when-new-entry-added-to-news-feed) and [Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199904/node-socket-io-connect-to-list-of-news-feed-urls)

From the answers of these 2 questions, I came to know that it's possible to notify the client. Even `socket.io` twitter streaming example is doing the same.

With the code given in [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295377/node-socket-io-update-client-when-new-entry-added-to-news-feed), I am getting news repeatedly from the server. In an example of twitter streaming with `socket.io` when a tweet on certain topic is made, client is updated with the same. I wanted to replicate the same with news feed but couldn't able to do it.

Could anyone please give me a direction with small example where client is notified when there is some update on server by using `node.js` and `socket.io` (any kind of update) or there are few topics to subscribe and client gets updates on subscribed topic only ???

Comment: To give you a simple example `io.emit('news', 'news has changed')` would emit a notification from the server to all active sockets.

Comment: @James - I got your point. May I know how twitter streaming example works for latest tweet on specific topic ???

Comment: What twitter streaming example?

Comment: It's on the home page of `socket.io` - @James

Comment: Well it looks like it's using the [node-tweet-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tweet-stream) library, looking at the source for it all it appears to do is periodically query the twitter API and emit events whenever it receives any data back. The example just hooks into those events to then notify the socket.

Comment: Yes node-tweet-stream module is there. So, how does client subscribe to specific topic ???- @James

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82938/discussion-between-chako-desai-and-james).

Comment: Your now bordering on asking how that particular module works which now means your going off-topic. If you want to know how that module works read the docs.